# Firebase Cloud Functions - Functions that has been deleted from code, aren't being deleted from CF

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

#### The Issue

When I remove a function from the cloud functions and redeploy the rest, I get a message in the terminal:

```
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your 
local source code:
        function1(us-central1)
        function2(us-central1)
Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. (y/N)
```

I type "y". Once I redeploy again, I get the same message, over and over. What am I missing?

#### Depenencies

```
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
```

Comment: If something about the Firebase CLI doesn't work the way you expect, file a bug report with the steps that anyone can take to reproduce the problem.  Make sure you have the latest version of `firebase-tools`.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's a known issue that was recently reported.

To fix this, and I quote Firebase's support:

> I'm sorry for the inconveniences, that is a known issue that was reported recently, please check this link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/982 . The fix is ready and should be available in the next release of the firebase-tools package. In the meantime there are two alternatives:
>
> - add the "--force" option:
>     `firebase deploy --force --only functions`
> - use the "delete" command:
>     `firebase functions:delete funcName1 functName2 ...`
>
> You can check more options like this:
>
> - firebase deploy --help
> - firebase functions:delete --help

WARNING! Depending on the firebase-tools version `--force` may delete all other functions. Remember to test prior.